# Gmail not using TLS to deliver email to apache james server even with Starttls enabled

Tags: ssl, gmail, tls1.2, starttls, james

I am using Apache james 2.3.2 server as an email proxy. Even though I have Starttls enabled on my server and all the ports. Gmail is not delivering the emails through TLS rather sending it non secure.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this happening was that, the JAVA Mail API which is used in Apache James, In n its Socketfetcher class runs a method called configureSSLSocket in this method the SSL socket that you create using the SocketFetcher class gets setEnabledProtocols method run on it.

By default the value that is set in this method is TLSv1 (even in the latest release). So if you are not setting the mail."protocol".ssl.protocols option in the session that you used to create the SSL Socket the Socket will be downgraded to TLSv1 and google on most of its servers no longer allows TLSv1 connections and hence falls back to plain text.